# javascript/jquery input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-mobile

I have form where a user can add more input boxes on button click.
User can have as much input boxes as they want.

I do not plan to add a button for removing fields.

They default number of input boxes is 2.
Say the user decides to add 3 more, now there are a total of 5.

For validation, I would like to check if the input box is empty or if the input has all spaces like: "      " no matter how many spaces as long as it has nothing else but space.
I can do the check for an empty input by checking length, but how can I check for the latter?
Is there a regular expression for any number of consecutive spaces?
Thanks!

PS: I am using jQuery with jQuery mobile

Comment: Would you mind a plain JavaScript solution?

Comment: @Schien The title says **javascript** /jquery and the tags include javascript so I'd say go for it.

Comment: Yeah sure :)
I'll see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an input field is blank by checking its `.value.length`, as you already know. To check if it only contains whitespace, then try this: (assuming that the input is stored in a variable called `input`)

```
if (!input.value.trim().length) // oh noes! it's blank or whitespace-filled!
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Comment: Thanks! marked as answer and +1 for reference.
trim() was what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Just be aware that .trim() method is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions. You can use jQuery's [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a few components:

- how to add input fields dynamically?
- how to loop through these fields and validate them as well?
- how to check whether a field really contains content, not just empty values?

We need to address all of these issues in a systematic manner:

Starting with the easiest - detecting empty string:

```
if (value.replace(/\s/g,'')=='') //string is empty
```

Next, to add input fields dynamically:

```
var myinput=document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(myinput);

//the trick here is to "remember" this element for later use
document.myinputs=[];
document.myinputs.push(myinput);
```

To check all your input fields, you check the static ones first, then loop through the dynamic input fields:

```
valid=true; //default to true unless detected otherwise
for (var i=0;i<document.myinputs.length;i++){
  var input=document.myinputs[i];
  if (input.value.replace(/\s/g,'')=='') valid=false;
}

alert(valid);
```

Comment: Thanks! but rvighne's answer was the closest one :)
trim() was what I needed, but looking at your answer and doing some quick google it does seem to fix the problem too.

Also, on adding input fields I used .clone() from jquery

Thanks! If only I could give +2